# Using a User uploaded file as an email template in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following Python code within a Django model to send emails to the 'owner' of the model.  I want admin to be able to upload files which will be used (if uploaded) or the default template files will be used if it has not be loaded.  This is the code:

```
def send_invitation(self):
    '''
    sends an invitation from admin to accept a listing
    '''

    try:
        if self.user or not self.email : return False
    except :
        try: email_body_template = Parameter.objects.get(name='send_invitation_email.txt').f
        except: email_body_template = 'listing_cms_integration/email/send_invitation_email.txt'
        try: email_subject_template = Parameter.objects.get(name='send_invitation_email_subject.txt').f
        except: email_subject_template = 'listing_cms_integration/email/send_invitation_email_subject.txt'

        context = Context()
        context['listing'] = self
        context['site'] = Site.objects.get_current().domain

        subject = render_to_string(email_subject_template, context)
        message = render_to_string(email_body_template, context)

        email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[self.email])
        email.send()

        return True
```

If I do not have a Parameter named 'send_invitation_email.txt' then it works fine.  When picking up Parameter as specified I get the following error.

> coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found

How do I convert my user uploaded file into one I can use as an email template?

**EDIT**

Added Parameters model

```
class Parameter (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'Title',
        max_length = 255,
        unique=True,
    )
    description = models.TextField()
    f = models.FileField (
        verbose_name = 'Input File',
        help_text = "Email body template"
    )
```

Comment: Please show your `Parameter` model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it.

I added `MEDIA_ROOT` to my `TEMPLATES` `DIRS`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            ...
            os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT),
            ],
        'OPTIONS': {
```

and I changed the function to pick up the filename

```
email_body_template = Parameter.objects.get(name='send_invitation_email.txt').f.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have send to render_to_string() function file instance instead string.
Try that:

```
email_body_template = Parameter.objects.get(name='send_invitation_email.txt').f.read()
```

Comment: That generates an error `TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/listing_cms_integration/listing/` and then shows the content of the file

Comment: Also, when using `email_body_template = 'listing_cms_integration/email/send_invitation_email.txt'` is is sending a file to be rendered